# How do I export variable columns to a CSV file using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, select, export-to-csv

I know how to export to CSV using PHP to query mySQL and populate the CSV. However, is it possible to have the users select what columns they would like to have and vary the SQL query accordingly?

I have established the connection to the database, added my query which is:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT x, y, z from a");
$result = mysql_query( $query, $conn ) or die( mysql_error( $conn ) );
header( 'Content-Type: text/csv' );
header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=export.csv' );
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result );
if ( $row )
{
echocsv( array_keys( $row ) );
}
while ( $row )
{
echocsv( $row );
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result );
}
function echocsv( $fields )
{
$separator = '';
foreach ( $fields as $field )
{
  if ( preg_match( '/\\r|\\n|,|"/', $field ) )
  {
    $field = '"' . str_replace( '"', '""', $field ) . '"';
  }
  echo $separator . $field;
  $separator = ',';
}
echo "\r\n";
}
```

Comment: yes, now with out more details that's all you get.

Comment: Yes it is possible. In that case you have to generate the particular SQL statements programatically.

Comment: how do i generate the SQL Statement programatically?

Comment: how about showing some code so we at least have a clue, do you rally think you have provided enough information for any one to be able to help you?

Comment: I have added in the necessary code. Any ideas? I am getting unknown column name errors..

Comment: What is it? A script? A website? A webservice? How do you interact with the "user"?

Comment: it is a web application and there is an HTML page with check boxes for users to select which fields they would like in their csv page. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is. You have to make a form where the user selects the fields they want to export, I'm thinking in a checkbox list where you list all the posible database fields the can get, and then create the query according the user selection. 
Ej:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <label><input name="fields[]" type="checkbox" value="name"> Username</label>
    <label><input name="fields[]" type="checkbox" value="birthdate"> Birthdate</label>
</form>
```

And then on the server side create the database query.

```
$sql = "SELECT `". implode("`, `", $_POST["fields"]) ."` FROM db_table";
```

Hope this help.

Comment: When i tried using this, I got the - unknown column author in fieldlist - error. Also, i used this type of query earlier:

    $query = sprintf("select x from y");